# How to Reset Password Django?

Tags: python, django

Somehow I've barely been able to find any information on this.  I've found one tutorial [here](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/django-resetting-passwords-with.html), but it's 4 years old, and doesn't seem to be much help.  I've also gone through the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/), but it doesn't give a lot of example code.

I have set up my `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name='login'),
    url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, {'post_reset_redirect' : '/accounts/password_reset_done/'}, name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password_reset_done/$', auth_views.password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^password_reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', auth_views.password_reset_confirm, {'post_reset_redirect' : '/accounts/password_done/'}, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^password_done/$', auth_views.password_reset_complete, name='password_done'),
    url(r'^auth/$', views.login_auth, name='login_auth'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register_user, name='register'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_user, name='logout'),
]
```

From what I gather, unless I am using custom templates (which I haven't tried since I can't get the included Django version to work,) then everything is done in `urls.py`.

I can get the `reset_password` page to load fine:

[image]

But when I submit the form, I get the following error:

[image]

I just spent two hours fixing this exact same issue to get the `reset_password` page to load, and now the same problem is happening, just in the `reset_password_confirm` part.  I've looked at a bunch of questions that address this exact error, but I have no idea what is causing the problem.  Dealing with a few lines in `urls.py` doesn't seem like it should be this hard...

Comment: Do you need it from web? You could do it from the shell `user = User.objects.get(username='myadmin')` and `user.set_password('mynewpassword')`

Comment: I do need it from web

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views Look for the reset pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Update your urls.py with

```
url(r'^password_reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})$', auth_views.password_reset_confirm, {'post_reset_redirect' : '/accounts/password_done/'}, name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

From the log I can see that it expect uidb64

Comment: Changing to `uidb64` didn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: The above code is worked for me. Can you try this, 
url(r'^password_reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', auth_views.password_reset_confirm, {'post_reset_redirect' : '/accounts/password_done/'}, name='password_reset_confirm'),

Comment: Still have the same problem unfortunately.  Is it possible there's something in another file that's causing this?  As you said, it works for you, I can't see anything wrong with the `urls.py` code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have exactly from the docs and it works perfect.

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls), name='admin'),  # admin interface
url(r'^login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='Login'),  # for user login
url(r'^logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='Logout'),  # logout
url(r'',include(admin.site.urls), name='admin'),  # logout
url(r'^admin/password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, name='admin_password_reset'),
url(r'^admin/password_reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$', auth_views.password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
url(r'^reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_complete, name='password_reset_complete'),
```

[Here is the link to the docs,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-a-password-reset-feature)
hope it helps.